# Gradle building issue

Tags: android, c++, gradle

I try to compile my project with native c-libs and get next error

```
/Users/eugene/KREF14001/app/src/main/jni/libC/PulseFilter.c: In function 'shapeMonoGame':
/Users/eugene/KREF14001/app/src/main/jni/libC/PulseFilter.c:696:5: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
/Users/eugene/KREF14001/app/src/main/jni/libC/PulseFilter.c:696:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

From this report I find that I must to use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile my code, but I don't know how to do it. Please, help me.

Comment: Okey, I find this option in Android.mk, but there were next code: LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE  := kref
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/h/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := libC/oouraFFT.c libC/PulseFilter.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS  += -std=c99
LOCAL_LDLIBS  := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: As you can see there are already wrote LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99, but I have the same problem yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in that the Gradle don't use your .mk files, but generate its own and use them. So it's useful to edit Android.mk and Application.mk. You can build your source code manually or edit ndk section of build.gradle.

Answer (score 3):

In the `build.gradle` file of your app, you can add `cFlags "-std=c99"` in the `ndk` block located within the `defaultConfig` block like this:

```
ndk {
    moduleName "libblur"
    abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
    stl "gnustl_static"
    cFlags "-std=c99"
    ldLibs "log"
}
```

Comment: with the experimental build, its not working. can you please suggest. Thanks